# Scan multiple image directories in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, directory

Im trying to scan multiple image directories using PHP and create an array that contains the exact path of each image and its name.

**Example directory tree**

```
main/
├─ sub-directory-1/
│  ├─ image1.png
│  ├─ image2.jpeg
│  ├─ image3.png
├─ sub-directory-2/
│  ├─ image1.png
├─ sub-directory-3/
│  ├─ image1.jpeg
│  ├─ imageX.png
```

**Example of desired array**

```
{
    0 : {name: "image1", path: "main/subdirectory-1/image1.png"},
    1 : {name: "image2", path: "main/subdirectory-1/image2.jpeg"},
    2 : {name: "image3", path: "main/subdirectory-1/image3.png"},
    .
    .
    .
    7 : {name: "imageX", path: "main/subdirectory-3/imageX.png"},
}
```

Comment: Ok, start with a for loop

Comment: The function [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) can help you. In the link there are some nice examples on how to use it

Comment: @Baracuda078 Thank you. The link provided me with some ideas. However, I didn't use the glob function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach that got me the desired result.

I hope this will help someone

```php
public function ImageScanner() {
    $current_dir = getcwd();
    $folderpath = 'PATH/TO/SOME/DIR/';

    // Determining if the path is a directory or not
    if (is_dir($folderpath)) {

        // Opening the directory
        $files = opendir($folderpath); {

            // Checking if the directory opened
            if ($files) {

                //Reading each element's name in the directory
                while (($subfolder = readdir($files)) !== false) {

                    // Checking for errors in filename
                    if ($subfolder != '.' && $subfolder != '..') {
                        $dirpath = 'SOME/SUB_DIR/PATH/' . $subfolder . '/';

                        // Checking and opening each file inside the sub directory
                        if (is_dir($dirpath)) {
                            $file = opendir($dirpath);
                            if ($file) {
                                
                                // Reading each element's name in the sub directory
                                while (($filename = readdir($file)) !== false) {
                                    if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {
                                        $image_path = '' . $dirpath . '' . $filename . '';

                                        // Creating array for each scanned file
                                        $key = array(
                                            'image_name' => trim($filename) ,
                                            'image_path' => str_replace('/SOME/PATH/', '', $image_path) ,
                                        );

                                        // Appending each image array
                                        $image_arrays[] = $key;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $image_arrays;
}
```